# Get full rows based on single column distinct

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, lambda, linq-to-entities

Actually I want to get the full table but it should be based on `Doc_Type==distinct`

Means it should only pick the records from table that has unique `Doc_Type`. I have tried with following but it returns me a single column into `tolist()` but I want to get full table. How can I do it?

```
var data = DB.tblDocumentTypes.Select(m => m.Doc_Type).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy`

```
 var data = DB.tblDocumentTypes.GroupBy(m => m.Doc_Type).Select(x => x.First());
```

Comment: can you please explain logic behind it? I will be thankful to you.

Comment: you first grouping all record by `Doc_Type`, and then get the first item form the each group.

Comment: is there any difference between m and x that you are using in above query?can I use m in both expressions?

Comment: @Sweetie no, there is no difference.you can use `m` or `x` in both.they are just symbols that represents your record and groups